# lapack/blas resources not found when installing matplotlib

Tags: python, module, installation, package

I need help with my program.
When I enter: `pip install matplotlib`, I have this error. This error also tells me about other installations, for example: numpy or pandas...

Could you help me, please? ..thanks

> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
>
> or:
>
> NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
>
> ---
>
> Command
>   "C:\Users\stoso\PycharmProjects_dp_praca\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   c:\users\stoso\pycharmprojects_dp_praca\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py
>   prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
>   C:\Users\stoso\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnwvjtrj5" failed with error code
>   1 in C:\Users\stoso\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ko7grh0n\scipy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your setuptools are not properly installed. Try this:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

And then again try installing matplotlib.

Comment: OK, with the other error - Visual Studio is required to compile the code. VS 14.0 worked with 3.5 and 3.6, but you are using 3.8 so all bets are off. Can you try installing updated 'Visual C++ build tools' ? You might be better off just installing Anaconda which comes bundled with all dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, but updated 'Visual C++ build tools' doesnt solve my problem, too. However, I will try to download and install Anaconda.

Comment: Nice, I install Anaconda 3 and "pip install matplotlib" is functional. However, when I install "pip install alphashape",  I have error:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.